# function in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$. $g$ defined as $g=$sign  $u$ on $K$ and $0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n-K$. Show that $g\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I tried to get this but I have not got any idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

This is way easier than it looks. The image of sign is $\lbrace -1, 0, 1 \rbrace$. Therefore the image of $g$ is a subset of $\lbrace -1, 0, 1 \rbrace$ and hence bounded.

For measurability note that
$$
g = \chi_K \cdot(\chi_{\lbrace u > 0 \rbrace} - \chi_{ \lbrace u < 0 \rbrace})
$$
As $u \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$, it is measurable, so ${\lbrace u > 0 \rbrace}$ and ${\lbrace u < 0 \rbrace}$ are measurable. $K$ is closed, hence meausrable. Characteristic functions of measurable sets are measurable. Differences and products of measurable functions are measurable.